# keep getting this error message when launching django server

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

[image: command line error]

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)` File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
  autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
  raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
  autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", 
  line 24, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
  app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\nyaknoiton\Desktop\Django 2\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
  import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psychology_app'
```

`

That is the command line after using the cd pyschology_project to get into the directory when i try to launch my django server using python manage.py runserver i get the above error

Comment: You try to import `psychology_app` somewhere in your code but it could not resolve. Make sure you point to the correct location.

Comment: Any idea how i can do that with